# Close all open ul when another ul is toggled by click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I've got a vertical dropdown menu for which I'm using jQuery toggle to open/close the submenus. 
It's working fine when the user clicks the parent item (for example 'About' the submenu opens and when they click it again the submenu closes again. However, if they don't click the parent item ('About') a second time to close it but click on a different parent item (let's say 'Industry') to open the submenu both submenus ('About' and 'Industry') are visble.
So I need it to work that 'About' automatically closes when 'Industry' is clicked. 
Here is the code :

```
<nav> 
<ul id="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list_item nav-about><a href="#">About</a>
        <div id="about-drop">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-list_item nav-industry"><a href="#">Industry</a>
        <div id="industry-drop">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list_item nav-application"><a href="#">Application</a>
        <div id="application-drop">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
 $('li.nav-about').click(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });

    $(' li.nav-industry').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
 $('li.nav-application').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
```

I've tried different things I found on stackoverflow already but could'nt get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u0swbhc9/2/)

```
$('li.nav-about').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
});

$(' li.nav-industry').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "fast");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
});
$('li.nav-application').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "fast");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
});
```

Just hide the other div when one is click.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#nav-list li').on('click', function() {
  $('#nav-list li').not(this).find('div').hide();
  $(this).find('div').toggle();
});
```

```css
.nav-list_item > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-list">
  <li class="nav-list_item nav-about"><a href="#">About</a>
    <div id="about-drop ">
      <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-list_item nav-industry"><a href="#">Industry</a>
    <div id="industry-drop ">
      <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-list_item nav-application"><a href="#">Application</a>
    <div id="application-drop ">
      <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

No need for so convoluted handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove redundant code like this:

```
 $('li.nav-list_item').click(function () {
    $('li.nav-list_item').find('ul').hide();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

You can substitute your js with this.